# Django — improve `startswith` performance

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-orm

How to improve performance of the following query?

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, db_index=True)

# This line is slow:
Worker.objects.filter(name__startswith='John')
```

I have already added an index to the model, but... it's simply not used. *However*, index does kick in when I do ordinary filtering without `startswith`:

```
# This line is fast:
Worker.objects.filter(name='John')
```

Why index is not used with `startswith`?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `startswith` expression translates to an SQL query containing the `LIKE` operator, which doesn't take advantage of the default index.

Solution: add an additional index with a special [operator class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-opclass.html):

```
CREATE INDEX "appname_model_field_like_idx" 
ON "appname_model" ("fieldname" varchar_pattern_ops);
```

Step by step:

1. First, create an empty migration:

   ```
   python3 manage.py makemigrations appName --empty
   ```
2. Add a custom RunSQL command:

   ```
   class Migration(migrations.Migration):

       dependencies = [
           ('stats', '0002_auto_2010213_0159.py'),
       ]

       operations = [
           migrations.RunSQL(
               sql=r'''CREATE INDEX "appname_model_field_like_idx" 
                       ON "appname_model" ("fieldname" varchar_pattern_ops);''',
               reverse_sql=r'DROP INDEX "appname_model_field_like_idx";'
           ),
       ]
   ```

Comment: Additional style point for the `reverse_sql`. It's always frustrating when it's missing.

Comment: It seems that Django already adds this index automatically (possibly ONLY when there is already an index on the referred field - I'm not sure).

Answer (score 1):

If your backend is MySQL, try using the case-insensitive `istartswith` to use the index:

`Worker.objects.filter(name__istartswith='John')`